# Laravel low performance on json response

Tags: php, json, laravel, performance

In my Laravel application, the data are loaded via ajax for a data table. The performance is very bad. So I created a test script to measure the loading time.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $mt1 = microtime(true);

        $data = $this->repo->all();

        $resource = ProjectResource::collection($data);

        $response  = response()->json($resource);

        $mt2 = microtime(true);

        dd($mt2 - $mt1);

    }
```

There are 200 rows in the DB.

The model has 4 relations.

The script above takes> 6s to render the data.

If I uncomment the line `$response  = response()->json($resource);`, the loading time is < 0.2s

What are the possibilities to speed up the render time for the JSON response?

The $data model:

[image]

Appends:

```
trait ProjectAttribute
{
    public function getActionAttribute()
    {
        return $this->editButton().$this->deleteButton();
    }

    public function editButton()
    {
        if (Auth()->user()->can('update salesOrder')) {
            return '<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.__('buttons.general.crud.edit').'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editProject mr-1" ><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>';
        }
        return "";
    }

    public function deleteButton()
    {
        if (Auth()->user()->can('delete salesOrder')) {
            return '<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.__('buttons.general.crud.delete').'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteProject" ><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>';
        }
        return "";
    }

    public function getActiveLabelAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->active) {
            return "<span class='badge badge-info'>Aktiv</span>";
        }
        return "<span class='badge badge-secondary'>Inaktiv</span>";
    }
}
```

The model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Project\Project;

use Altek\Accountant\Contracts\Recordable;
use Altek\Accountant\Recordable as RecordableTrait;
use App\Models\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Project extends Model implements Recordable
{
    use ProjectAttribute, ProjectMethod, ProjectRelationship, ProjectScope, Uuid, RecordableTrait, SoftDeletes;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'sales_order_id',
        'project_leader_id',
        'project_type_id',
        'project_status_id'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'action',
        'activeLabel',
        'salesOrderName',
        'projectLeaderName',
        'creatorName',
        'statusName',
        'statusLabel',
        'typeLabel'
    ];

    protected $with = ['projectLeader', 'salesOrder', 'projectType', 'projectStatus'];
}
```

The resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Project extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'                =>      $this->id,
            'name'              =>      $this->name,
            'description'       =>      $this->description,
            'sales_order_name'  =>      $this->salesOrder->name,
            'sales_order'       =>      $this->salesOrder,
            'project_leader'    =>      $this->projectLeader,
            'project_leader_name'=>     $this->projectLeader->full_name,
            'creator'            =>     $this->creator,
            'creator_name'      =>      $this->creator->full_name,
            'type'              =>      $this->projectType,
            'type_name'         =>      $this->projectType->name,
            'type_label'        =>      $this->projectType->typeLabel,
            'status'            =>      $this->projectStatus,
            'status_name'       =>      $this->projectStatus->name,
            'status_label'      =>      $this->projectStatus->statusLabel,
            'created_at'        =>      $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d'),
            'action'            =>      $this->action
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: are you eager loading the relationships?

Comment: Yes, the relations are loaded.

Comment: I just added the $data model in my question.

Comment: what is in your `$appends` array?

Comment: I added the appends in the question above.

Comment: Does someone have an idea what i can do to speed up the application?

Comment: Can you post the resource source code as well as the model? If you don't have the `$with` array set up in your model, then you are not eager loading the relations, as @lagbox said in the first place

Comment: @mdexp I added the model and the resource code.

Comment: Is `creator` a relationship? If so can you try to eager load that one as well? If that doesn't help try to comment all the lines in the resource and test each line on its own to see how it affects performance

Comment: Also, how many records are you trying to render?

Comment: I added also creator to eager load. now, it takes 3.5 seconds for 500 rows.
Actually, i removed the resource function. 
`$data = Project::all(); return response()->json($data);`

Comment: What about the policies / gates you call with ->can() these are called on each model can you show them?

Comment: Any updates on this one? Would like to know if there is any specific steps taken to improve the performance. My application is very similar and database queries are quick.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to profile a request to get some information as to what is taking the server so long to respond.

- [BlackFire](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#profiling-applications-with-blackfire) - Which comes by default in Laravel Homestead in development or Laravel Forge for production
- [Laravel DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) - Can also be used in development (my personal favorite)

These will give you a lot more information regarding the parts of your code that may be taking time to complete and there are several more if you google around for Laravel or PHP profilers to find something that suits your needs.

Comment: Also use [laravel-query-detector](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector) to detect N+1 query problems with uneager loaded relations

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Enlightn](https://www.laravel-enlightn.com/), a tool to boost your Laravel app's performance and security. It scans your code and server configurations to provide actionable recommendations on improving performance and security.